# $\lim\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\delta n\rfloor} \frac{n^k}{k!}e^{-n}$ and Poisson distribution

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory, power-series

> **Problem:** Let $X_1,X_2\ldots$ be some independent random variables with Poisson distribution with parameter 1. Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ sequence $S_n-(1-\epsilon)n$ diverges to $\infty$ almost surely where $S_n=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n$.

**My attempt:**

Since $Y_i \sim Poiss(a_i)\Rightarrow Y_1+\ldots+Y_k \sim Poiss(a_1+\ldots +a_k)$ we have $S_n \sim Poiss(n)$.

If $\epsilon > 1$ then the claim is obvious. Suppose $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and let $\delta = 1-\epsilon$.
We need to show that for any arbitrarily chosen M: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{P}(S_n > M+\delta n) = 1$. We have: 
$$LHS = \sum_{k=\lceil M+\delta n \rceil}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{k!}e^{-n} = 1- \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor M+\delta n \rfloor}\frac{n^k}{k!}e^{-n} \leq 1-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor cn \rfloor}\frac{n^k}{k!}e^{-n}$$
for some $c\in (0,1)$ and $n$ large enough. I've tried to estimate this sum using stirling formula, but it didn't work for me. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Have you studied the law of large numbers?

Comment: Not yet. But now Iḿ reading on it on the wikipedia and it indeed seems strongly connected.

Comment: Could you please explain what is M?

Comment: Well, we've had to show that some sequence diverges to $\infty$, hence for some index $n$ large enough this sequence by definition should be greater than any arbitrary chosen number M. You're right I didn't specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it:

We want to show that $\Pr ( S_n - (1-\epsilon)n \geq M) \to 1$, hence it's the same as proving that $\Pr ( S_n - (1-\epsilon)n < M) \to 0$. I'll use Chebyshev's inequality:
$$
\Pr(|X-\mathrm{E}X|\leq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathrm{Var}X}{\epsilon^2}
$$
The key to solve this problem was to see that for $n$ large enough:
$$
\Pr(S_n - n  < M -n\epsilon)\leq \Pr (S_n - n < -\frac{n\epsilon}{2}) = \Pr (S_n - \mathrm{E}S_n < -\frac{n\epsilon}{2}) \leq \Pr (|S_n - \mathrm{E}S_n| \geq \frac{n\epsilon}{2}) \leq \frac{n}{(\frac{n\epsilon}{2})^2} \to 0
$$
The penultimum inequality was probably the hardest one to see, but once you've guessed you should use the Chebyshev's inequality the problem becomes quite simple. Please correct me if my solution is somehow wrong.